# SpriteKit, Swift - How do I tap the button instead of starting my game?

Tags: ios, swift, button, gestures

Ok, I currently have four gesture recognises in my class

```
let TapUpRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

let swipeRightRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeLeftRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeDownRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
```

I have recently added a button node in my scene and was trying to get it to click without using the touches function and was wondering how I implement it so I can click on the screen to start my game but also click the button when I want, without starting the game.

Here is my tap function that moves the player forward currently:

```
func tapUp(){

    let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: amountToMove, duration: 0.1)

    thePlayer.runAction(move)

    clearNodes()

}
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking, what do you want the button (what button? I do not see any button) to do?

Comment: i want to be able to make the tap gesture recogniser to recognise whether i have tapped on a button or just on the regular view. Right now I have it so it moves the player Sprite when I tap anywhere on the screen. do you understand? But I don't want to use the function touches ended or any of those functions because it conflicts when I try to swipe across the screen.

Comment: Try enabling "MultipleTouch" in the properties inspector of the view you're working with and then add the touchesBegan() function to see if it allows both touches. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_Touch,_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application